# Выравнивание по центру css

Tags: html, css, css3, position, center

Блок обведённый в красную рамку фиксированный `position: fixed;`, необходимо его каким-нибудь образом выровнять вертикально по центру. Высота самого блока динамическая, то есть может меняться в зависимости от наполенеия его контентом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как на счет хоть какого-нибудь кода? какой-нибудь html/css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.redBlock{
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Центрируйте с помощью трансформации!